# How to create an angular form that uses session storage that can be called throughout the html pages

Tags: html, angularjs, local-storage

I want to create a form on an index page that can store data via session storage. I also want to make sure that whatever data(let's say name) ... is remembered and used throughout the site with angular. I have researched pieces of this process but I do not understand how to write it or really even what it's called.

Any help in the right direction would be useful as I am in the infant stages of all of this angular business. Let me know.

Comment: Take a look at [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache). Have a go using this (i have it working well on a project) then post some code back here once you've tried something. Hint: use angular-cache in a and angular factory that exposes get, set and reset methods that use the cache

Comment: If you use ngRoute and factory, you can to advance on data input, preserving the data. You don't need to use back sessions to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The service you want is angular-local-storage.

Just configure it in your app.js file:

```
localStorageServiceProvider
  .setStorageType('sessionStorage');
```

And then use it in the controller that contains whatever data you want to remember. Here is an example of a controller that loads the session storage data on initialization, and saves it when a user fires $scope.doSearch through the UI. This should give you a good place to start.

```
    (function () {

angular.module("pstat")
       .controller("homeCtrl", homeCtrl);

  homeCtrl.$inject = ['$log', 'dataService', 'localStorageService', '$http'];
   function homeCtrl ($log, dataService, localStorageService, $http) { {
     if (localStorageService.get("query")) { //Returns null for missing 'query' cookie
        //Or store the results directly if they aren't too large
        //Do something with your saved query on page load, probably get data
        //Example:
        dataService.getData(query)
        .success( function (data) {})
        .error( function (err) {})
     }
     $scope.doSearch = function (query) {
       vm.token = localStorageService.set("query", query);
       //Then actually do your search
     }
   })
}()
```

Comment: I guess I am not following. I need to have something in a form ... and throughout the site be able to populate it with the {{ }} throughout the site. I am sorry for my lack of words but I do not know the correct terminology.

Comment: Do you know how to use ng-model or ng-submit to get form data onto the scope of a controller?

Comment: No sir. I didnt even know that was a thing until just now.